# How do I make a canvas auto grow to fit its content

Tags: silverlight, layout, silverlight-4.0, scroll

I am creating a portal type dashboard for our app. The controls are added on the fly. I have a page, with a tabcontrol. In the tab control I add TabItems on the fly with a canvas on it. The canvas handles the mouse events to move the controls around.

I need to allow the users to create a layout bigger than the current size of the tab item... so I inserted a scrollviewer in the tab item and put the canvas onto it. However, the canvas doesn't seem to expand automatically to contain the content.

How can I made the canvas expand to hold all its content within the scroll viewer which will allow me to scroll around the canvas it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two previous SO posts on how to manipulate the size of a Canvas:

- [Force a custom WPF Control to resize correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518674/force-a-custom-wpf-control-to-resize-correctly)
- [WPF: How to make canvas auto-resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855334/wpf-how-to-make-canvas-auto-resize)